# Welcome emails being blocked by receivers email clients

Tags: email, server

Our site is hosted by a company on a remote server. Our welcome emails used to be received fine, but as we've grown many customers are complaining about never seeing their emails. Some end up in junk/spam folders, which isn't ideal but is fine since it still gets through. But some email domains, such as comcast.net, aren't evening letting them hit the inbox. Is there anything I can do about this? Or do I need to contact our server host? Is there somewhere else I should ask about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by contacting your hosting provider. It is possible that you IP address has been out on a blacklist and Comcast blocks them. It is also possible that your reverse DNS lookup is incorrect and Comcast is rejecting the emails for that reason. The fact that they once worked and now don't point to the conclusion that your IP address and been registered on a blacklist site.

If you are on a shared host it is possible that another site on the same server caused the issue. In the end your hosting provider will have to help solve the issue.

Comment: You beat me to the answer.. My ADD kicked in and I was in another window :)

Answer (score 2):

We frequently run into this problem and have no end of issues with generic PHP mail. We have taken to offloading all mail to a dedicated service (like google apps), creating appropriate DNS/MX record modifications and then sending all mail via SMTP using something like

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

MXtoolbox is a great service for checking if you domain/IP has fallen afoul of any blacklists.

Comment: The given url is not exist now

Answer (score 1):

This is outside the scope of the Magento forum, however a starting point would be:

- Ensure your sending email server has a reverse DNS entry
- Check to make sure your email server and/or IP are not on any spam / block lists
- Implement SPF (Sender Policy Framework)